# Disassemble and remove bathtub–shower combination

Tags: bathroom, bathtub

I need to remove this bathtub with shower walls in order to investigate and repair water damage near the bottom of the wall. **How do I disassemble, loosen, and remove the walls and tub without damaging them?**

The brand is Lasco Bathware. The unit consists of two pieces: the tub and the U-shaped shower walls on top of it. I have not been able to find a model number or installation instructions, so I don't know how the shower walls are attached to the studs/wall behind it.

[image]

Comment: It might be easier to investigate from some other place. Where is the leaked water appearing?

Comment: @benrudgers, There are signs of water damage at the front right end of where the surround overlaps the tub, and in the walls behind and to the right of the tub. The floor has rotted in that area, so I'll have to remove the tub and the bottom parts of two walls to replace part of the floor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to cut the drywall away from the edge of the tub and surround.  The drywall should overlap a flange of the tub/surround.  That should expose the screws and clips holding the tub and surround to the studs.  If you are lucky, the installer didn't also use glue to attach the surround to the studs as well.

Found link to install instructions.  http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/cf/cf84df47-d48f-4392-80e4-79ec296343ad.pdf